# JSF:Automatic trigger event after page load

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using this primefaces media tag to view the PDF

```
<p:media value="#{bean.path}" width="100%" height="600px">    
</p:media>
```

Now after loading the PDF file from a specific folder in this page`(ViewPDF.xhtml)` I want to delete that PDF file from the folder.I searched and tried `<f:event>` tag for this and used its `type="postAddToView"` but it deletes the file before showing the PDf in browser and I want that It should be deleted after loading the PDF file in browser.What should I use for this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file is not finished downloading "after page load". It's downloaded by an entirely separate HTTP request which is starts after page load. You *could* map a filter on the desired URL pattern and perform the job after `chain.doFilter()` call. But this is somewhat strange.

I understand that you're generating PDF reports which should be shown on submit only. In that case, you should create a separate servlet which generates the PDF based on some request parameters and write it to the response output stream directly instead of a file output stream. Finally just let JSF generate the right URL for that servlet, with the proper request parameters.

E.g.

```
public void submit() {
    // ...

    path = externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/pdf"
        + "?foo=" + URLEncoder.encode(foo, "UTF-8")
        + "?bar=" + URLEncoder.encode(bar, "UTF-8")
        + "?baz=" + URLEncoder.encode(baz, "UTF-8");
}
```

and a servlet like this (assuming that you're using iText to generate PDFs):

```
@WebServlet("/pdf/*")
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
        String bar = request.getParameter("bar");
        String baz = request.getParameter("baz");
        // ...

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
        // ...
    }

}
```

If you'd like to hide the request parameters away, you could alternatively also store them in the session by an autogenerated/unique ID and pass that as request parameter instead.